# WSO2 ESB - how to enable proxy service on two http ports

Tags: http, ports, wso2-esb

I want to expose same rest api on two http ports i.e.

client calls -->  wso2 esb, ESB need to have same service to be exposed on two ports
 /restAPIservice on port 8281 and /restAPIservice on port 8282 .

this use case is for scenario like 8282 for external world and 8281 for internal applications.

Please let me know whether this is possible with wso2 esb directly.

Answer (score 0):

This not possible to do it in WSO2 esb for proxy service or REST service. In your case, you can bring up another wso2 esb server with port offset and synchronize the configuration using deployment synchronization. Having said that, it is possible to give a port value for HL7 Services in wso2 esb.

Comment: Hi Vanji, I have enabled 2 ports on one instance. just created new transport reviver with different port in axis2.xml. but the new http port  urls is visible for only proxy service. But not for the rest. if some body know how to enable multiple http ports for rest api, please respond me back.